# Why must 4/5 result __reduce__ return iterators?

Tags: python, pickle

The optional 4th and 5th return values of [`__reduce__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) are, from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__):

- Optionally, an iterator (and not a sequence) yielding successive list items. These list items will be pickled, and appended to the object...
- Optionally, an iterator (not a sequence) yielding successive dictionary items, which should be tuples of the form `(key, value)`. These items will be pickled and stored to the object using `obj[key] = value`...

Why are these values required to be iterators? It seems weird that if we have a list of things to append, we have to call `iter` on it before returning it. Why does the pickle protocol require iterators here, and why can't it call `iter` for us?

Comment: `__reduce__` has been around for a while but is rather low-level. It is mostly there for C extension types that need more control over how they are re-instantiated. As such, this API is more primitive.

Comment: The original [commit](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/3c89049fe628) doesn't explain why `iter()` wasn't used here, but that same commit does adds the batching behaviour that uses these two arguments as iterables. My suspicion is again that `__reduce__` exposes low-level pickling behaviour and expects the caller to know what they are doing.